# Why ethernet shield is not connect to server?

Tags: arduino, ethernet

I am trying to connect server with using arduino uno, ethernet shield and hc-sr06 sensors. It connects to server without using sensor codes but when I add sensor codes it is not connected.

Here is the code without sensor codes; I see "In loop2" log on serial port.

```
#include <Ethernet.h>
#include <SPI.h>

byte mac[] = { 0xDE, 0xAD, 0xBE, 0xEF, 0xFE, 0xED  }; 
EthernetClient client;

void setup() { 
   Serial.begin(9600);

   if (Ethernet.begin(mac) == 0) {
     Serial.println("Failed to configure Ethernet using DHCP"); 
   }

   delay(10000); // GIVE THE SENSOR SOME TIME TO START

 }

 void loop(){
   Serial.println("In loop"); 

   if (client.connect("www.xxxxx.com",80)) { 
     Serial.println("In loop2");
     client.println("POST /update_data2.php HTTP/1.1"); 
     client.println("Host: www.xxxxx.com"); // SERVER ADDRESS HERE TOO
     client.println("Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded"); 
     client.print("Content-Length: "); 
     client.println(txData.length()); 
     client.println(); 
     client.print(txData); 
   } 

   if (client.connected()) { 
     client.stop();  
   }

   delay(30000); 
 }
```

Here is the code with using sensor codes; I dont see "In loop2" log on serial port.

```
#include <Ethernet.h>
#include <SPI.h>

const int trigger_pin_1 = 12;
const int echo_pin_1 = 13;

const int trigger_pin_2 = 11;
const int echo_pin_2 = 10;

const int trigger_pin_3 = 9;
const int echo_pin_3 = 8;

const int led_1_r = 2;
const int led_1_g = 3;

const int led_2_r = 4;
const int led_2_g = 5;

const int led_3_r = 6;
const int led_3_g = 7;

int sure_1 ;
int mesafe_1 ;

int sure_2 ;
int mesafe_2 ;

int sure_3 ;
int mesafe_3 ;

byte mac[] = { 0xDE, 0xAD, 0xBE, 0xEF, 0xFE, 0xED  }; 
EthernetClient client;

String txData ="";

void setup() { 

  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println("In setup"); 

  if (Ethernet.begin(mac) == 0) {
    Serial.println("Failed to configure Ethernet using DHCP"); 
  }

  delay(5000);

  pinMode(led_1_r , OUTPUT);
  pinMode(led_1_g , OUTPUT);

  pinMode(led_2_r , OUTPUT);
  pinMode(led_2_g , OUTPUT);

  pinMode(led_3_r , OUTPUT);
  pinMode(led_3_g , OUTPUT);

  pinMode(trigger_pin_1 , OUTPUT);
  pinMode(trigger_pin_2 , OUTPUT);
  pinMode(trigger_pin_3 , OUTPUT);

  pinMode(echo_pin_1 ,INPUT);
  pinMode(echo_pin_2 ,INPUT);
  pinMode(echo_pin_3 ,INPUT);


  delay(3000);
}

void loop(){
  Serial.println("In loop"); 

  digitalWrite(trigger_pin_1 , HIGH);
  digitalWrite(trigger_pin_2 , HIGH);
  digitalWrite(trigger_pin_3 , HIGH);

  delayMicroseconds(1000);

  digitalWrite(trigger_pin_1 , LOW);
  digitalWrite(trigger_pin_2 , LOW);
  digitalWrite(trigger_pin_3 , LOW);

  sure_1 = pulseIn(echo_pin_1 , HIGH);
  mesafe_1 = (sure_1/2) / 29.1;

  sure_2 = pulseIn(echo_pin_2 , HIGH);
  mesafe_2 = (sure_2/2) / 29.1;

  sure_3 = pulseIn(echo_pin_3 , HIGH);
  mesafe_3 = (sure_3/2) / 29.1;

  delay(100);

  Serial.print("mesafe_1:");
  Serial.println(mesafe_1);
  Serial.print("mesafe_2:");
  Serial.println(mesafe_2);
  Serial.print("mesafe_3:");
  Serial.println(mesafe_3);


  if (mesafe_1 <= 10)
  {
     digitalWrite(led_1_r , HIGH);
     delay(100);
     clienConnect(1,0);
  }else{
     digitalWrite(led_1_g , HIGH);
     delay(100);
     clienConnect(1,1);
    }


  if (mesafe_2 <= 10)
  {
     digitalWrite(led_2_r , HIGH);
     delay(100);
     clienConnect(2,0);
  }else{
     digitalWrite(led_2_g , HIGH);
     delay(100);
     clienConnect(2,1);
    }


  if (mesafe_3 <= 10)
  {
     digitalWrite(led_3_r , HIGH);
     delay(100);
     clienConnect(3,0);
  }else{
     digitalWrite(led_3_g , HIGH);
     delay(100);
     clienConnect(3,1);
    }

  delay(100);
}

void clienConnect(int id, int valuex){
  Serial.println("In clienConnect");

  txData = "senid=" + (String)id + "&senvalue=" + (String)valuex;

  Serial.print("  txData:");
  Serial.println(txData);

  Serial.println("In clienConnect2");

  if (client.connect("www.xxxxx.com",80)) 
  { 
    Serial.println("In loop2");
    client.println("POST /update_data.php HTTP/1.1"); 
    client.println("Host: www.xxxxx.com"); 
    client.println("Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded"); 
    client.print("Content-Length: "); 
    client.println(txData.length()); 
    client.println(); 
    client.print(txData); 
  } 
  Serial.println("In loop3");

  if (client.connected()) { 
    Serial.println("In loop4");
    client.stop();  
    Serial.println("In loop5");
  }

  Serial.println("In loop6");
  delay(1000); 

  }
```

Why is not client connect to server when I add sensor codes? Could you please help me in this subject? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

The Ethernet shield is connected to the SPI pins, which happen to be pins 11, 12, and 13 on the Arduino Uno. Pin 10 is also used for the Ethernet Shield CS pin. (reference: https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/Ethernet)

In your second code:

```
const int trigger_pin_1 = 12;
const int echo_pin_1 = 13;

const int trigger_pin_2 = 11;
const int echo_pin_2 = 10;
```

You are using those pins for your HC-SR06 sensors. You need to use different pins for those sensors.